# Regression with random vs uniform distribution of a covariate

Tags: regression, estimation, sample, uniform-distribution, curve-fitting

Suppose we have some population of individuals, each having X and Y variable. I know that in the population, most individuals have low values of X, but I want to find regression formula for low as well as for high values of X.

Consider 2 scenarios:

A) I take random sample from the population, measure X and Y, and estimate the formula.

B) I sample X uniformly, measure X and Y, and estimate the formula.

Which approach is better, and how exactly they differ from the inference POV? We commonly use the first one, but in the second, we have better cover of X values (so the formula will work 'equally' for low and high values of X).